# cell.accessoryView always on top. Can it be sent to the back?

Tags: ios, accessoryview

I have set cell.accessoryView and another image.  But accessoryView is always on top.  Is there a way to send this to the back?  I've tried:

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-right.png"]];
[cell sendSubviewToBack:cell.accessoryView];
```

Any ideas?  I guess I could just create a separate image, instead of using accessoryView, but wondering if there's an easier way.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to send it to back ?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you want to achieve and do not try to determine the solution in your question.

Comment: I'm adding a 'swipe row to bring up some more buttons'.  When I swipe and change buttons.hidden = NO;, it shows up behind the accessoryView image I set.  I want buttons to be in front of accessoryView.

Comment: So you basically want the accessoryview to be hidden as soon as you show your buttons?

Comment: Yep, hiding would work.  But to hide it, I think I need to keep track of all of my cells, so I can hide the accessoryView for the right cell in my UISwipeGestureRecognizer.  Was hoping there might be a slicker way :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for you ...
when you want to hide it from the cell ... you can't send it to back because the cell views are arranged by Apple defaults ...

[image]

but u can hide it by setting the `accessoryView` to a **Fake Image** (I meant image that's not found in the disk) ...

`cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fake.png"]];`

I hope that helps anyone...